# How to create Windows Symbolic Link (to UNC path) with Java

Tags: java, nio, symlink

I am trying to create symbolic link of folder on my machine to the shared drive of other m/c
 i.e. If I have 'test' folder in D drive. I want to create its Symbolic Link on shared folder say "\\hjds22\Test". When I tried with below code it gives me `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException`.
Code is given below:

```
        Path newLink =Paths.get( "\\\\hjds22\\Test\\newLink");
        Path target = Paths.get("D:\\test");
        try {
            Files.createSymbolicLink(newLink, target);
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException x) {
            // Some file systems do not support symbolic links.
            System.err.println(x);
        }
```

Note: I have `full rights` on shared folder. I have also executed `fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation L2L:1 R2R:1 L2R:1 R2L:1` on both m/c's.

Comment: What was the exception? Is the drive NTFS?

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mklink /j dir target")`

Answer (score 0):

Windows shortcuts are not supported by Java.

You have to use an external library. Such as [jShortcut](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~jimmc/jshortcut/), which comes with a jni dll.

This works very fine, except that the dll is a 32bits dll. And I (personaly) failed to compile it to 64bits. This will require to force your application to run with a 32bits jre.